# Rapid Application Development (RAD model)

Tags: performance, web-applications, software-design

Someone could give me some informations about books sources or websites who talk and explain the RAD model "Rapid Application Development" please, I'm a new student at this field "Computer science" and the teacher asked me to make a presentation in frensh on the subject of RAD model.

Thank you !

Comment: Hi, this platform is used for your specific questions to find answers, please make deeper research on the internet to find out more resources.

Comment: Try a simple google search for "Rapid Application Development recommended books". Seems to give a good starting point for further investigation.